# Read csv that is not well written

Tags: java, regex, csv

i've got a csv that isn't well written:

The header is:

```
"xxx"|"yyy"|"zzz"|"nnn"|"...."
```

so what i try is to create a scanner and split on pipe:

```
Scanner scanner   = new Scanner(new File("myCsv.csv"));
int first = 1;
String line;
String row[];
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
   line = scanner.nextLine();
   row  = line.split("\\|");
   if(first==1){
    first = 0;
    continue;
   }
   ...
}
```

Unfortunately, inside a column of the csv i found a new line so the "nextLine" isn't a good way to fetch an entire row.

Another issue is that the pipe is present inside a column.. something like:

```
"field1"|"field|2"|"field3\n"|"..."
```

So i think that the best way to parse that csv is to create a regex pattern that matches `".."|".."` string.

Is there someone that can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: How is `"` specified inside the quotes?

Comment: That looks like well written `|` delimited CSV to me.

Comment: If you look at "field1"|"field|2"|"field3\n"|"..." and split for pipe, it split field and 2 as two fields instead one field

Comment: I mean, when the field contains `"`, how does the CSV look like?

Comment: Fix the source. Don't add compensating bugs.

Comment: This isn't a bug in the CSV, it's completely valid

Comment: Why do you say this file *isn't well written*, and why do not you look for an existent csv library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your csv don't contain any escaped double quotes, i would suggest you to do matching instead of splitting.

```
"(?s)\".*?\""
```

`(?s)` called dotall modifier which makes the dot in your pattern to match even line breaks.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/42)

```
String s = "\"xxx\"|\"yyy|bar\"|\"zzz\"|\"nn\n" + 
        "n\"|\"....\"";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?s)\".*?\"").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

**Output:**

```
"xxx"
"yyy|bar"
"zzz"
"nn
n"
"...."
```

Use capturing groups, if you don't want double quotes at the final output.

```
String s = "\"xxx\"|\"yyy|bar\"|\"zzz\"|\"nn\n" + 
        "n\"|\"....\"";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?s)\"(.*?)\"").matcher(s);
    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Output:

```
xxx
yyy|bar
zzz
nn
n
....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\|(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

You can use this to split your string.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/48

Answer (score 0):

Pick yourself an already existing [CSV Library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) that will handle this and other issues for you.  CSV isn't as straight forward as "comma separated" so no point reinventing the wheel

Comment: Are you sure that it works for this case, where the field can contain unescaped new line character inside quote?

Comment: I haven't used that specific library, being it's an Apache project so I would guess it conforms to the CSV spec correctly

Answer (score -2):

Just tested with a simple String split with this regex `["][|]["]`.

So you can use your code with this: `row  = line.split("[\"][|][\"]");`

Or my test with a simple string split:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "\"xxx\"|\"yyy\"|\"zzz\"|\"nnn\"|\"....\"";
    String regex = "[\"][|][\"]";

    String[] textArray= text.split(regex);
    for(String part:textArray){
        System.out.println(part);
    }        
}
```

This will output:

```
"xxx
yyy
zzz
nnn
...."
```

So just remove the " at the beginning and end and you have your splitted string.

[You can also test any regex on regex test websites.](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: What about new line inside column?